# java Ignite log4j issue

Tags: java, log4j, ignite

Can't tune proper logging for Ignite. Acorrding to manual, i have config with log4j

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="gridLogger">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="config/ignite-log4j.xml"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

My pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I used a log4j example ignite-log4j.xml from Ignite package.

Why am i still seeing this in console?

```
jun 30, 2020 2:02:59 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Failed to resolve default logging config file: config/java.util.logging.properties
```

I start Ignite at Intelj.
I thought that default logger should be disabled after enabling log4j. Am i right or some extra settings or dependecies required?

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK. Are you sure that Log4J config is not actually used? If you direct log to file, does it appear there?

A lot of things can trigger a sole JUL logging invocation, maybe it's nothing.

Comment: Contrary, i am sure that ignite-log4j.xml actualy used. But i expected not to see  java.util.logging errors, when log4j enabled. I see a file appeared in log directory, but it is empty. Initialy, i would to get correct outout to Intelij console.

Comment: You can try to add breakpoint to JUL code, see where this invocation comes from.

Comment: It only actual for my old version 2.3.0. Ignite 2.8.1 ignore this file, when log4j enabled. Thank you